# Should I use a mycorrhizal inoculant when transplanting 4.5" caliper white oaks?

Tags: transplanting, soil-amendment, oak

The site is on the east end of Long Island. Zone 6b. It is actually a re-vegetation of a forested area from which we removed over 40 mature pitch pines that had succumbed to some pine beetle. There are currently some small black and scrub oaks in the area, among other things.

Would these white oaks benefit from one of the commercial inoculants available, or does the reasonably undisturbed soil contain all that will be needed for good acclimation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless it's a large fraction of the value of the trees (seems unlikely) might as well give them all the help they can get. Might not be needed, but if it helps any of them, and it's not too expensive, might as well.

Answer (score 3):

It never hurts to add mychorrizah. It's like giving a probiotic boost to the tree. Because you are planting a tree, you don't need to put soil additives in the tree pit. Because their tree roots will spread to about 40 feet in diameter, they will move beyond the original planting hole (and the soil additives) very quickly.

Comment: If you are linked to the web site in your answer you should disclose it or it could be removed or edited

Comment: Sorry. I saw a [description of link] when reviewing the answer and thought I was supposed to add a link. My mistake. I won't fill that in, in the future.